# Ubuntu is showing Purple screen after login. Display settings

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I connected my Laptop with External Display (on Ubuntu) and set it to Second-Screen only. I did some changes in the resolution using Terminal (Change the ratio from4:3 to 16:9 using xrandr). Now Ubuntu is showing a purple screen right after login and it isn't working. I am Dual-Booting Windows with Ubuntu.

I think it is because I connected Ubuntu with External Display and something else is done whether I don't know I added this to using the terminal to permanent the effect of my changes.

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
sudo chown gdm:gdm ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
```

Comment: So would start with removing the file you copied to `/var/lib/gdm3/`

Comment: I can't do anything as I can't access it. GRUB either cannot.

Comment: you say "purple screen after login" so you can from grub but you can also using a live session. Plus you can likely also still do control alt f2 to enter a console